# Filter haskell list based on another list

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have two lists:

```
l1 = [True, False, True]

l2 = [1, 2, 3]
```

I want the result of my function to be `[1, 3]`, as they map to `True` in the other list

This is what I have thought of:

```
map2 [] [] res = res
map2 (o:os) (x:xs) res = if o then map2 (os xs (res ++ [x])) else map2 (os xs (res ++ []))
```

We can map 2 lists at the same time. Basically if `o` is True, then I want to add `x` to the list, otherwise I don't. I think this should work, but it doesn't.

I get that **Couldn't match expected type `[a0] -> [a0] -> [Bool]'**

Comment: It helps if you write your functions with explicit type signatures.

Comment: Hint: Use `zip`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you write brackets the wrong way. If you write brackets like `f (g x)`, then Haskell interprets this, like a language in the C/C++/Java language family would do that like `f(g(x))`.

Here you write expressions like:

```
map2 (os xs (res ++ [x]))
```

So according to the syntax, `os` should be a function, and `xs` its parameter. But that is not the case.

We can solve the problem like:

```
map2 :: [Bool] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
map2 [] [] res = res
map2 (o:os) (x:xs) res = if o then map2 os xs (res ++ [x]) else map2 os xs res
```

but still this is *not* the best way to handle it, since:

1. it might happen that the two lists do not have the same length, in that case the function will raise an error; and
2. `(++)` runs linear with the length of the first list, making this a quadratic algorithm.

We can solve these problems by writing it like:

```
map2 :: [Bool] -> [a] -> [a]
map2 (o:os) (x:xs) | o = x : map2 os xs
                   | otherwise = map2 os xs
map2 _ _ = []
```

we thus no longer need an *accumulator* here.

## Using `zip`

You can use [**`zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zip) to iterate over two lists concurrently and produce tuples of those elements, for example:

```
Prelude> zip [True, False, True] [1,2,3]
[(True,1),(False,2),(True,3)]
```

We can then use this, for example in list comprehension to filter, and yield the corresponding elements, like:

```
map2 :: [Bool] -> [a] -> [a]
map2 l1 l2 = [ y | (x, y) <- zip l1 l2, x ]
```

or we can, like [@WillNess says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54726021/filter-haskell-list-based-on-another-list/54726142?noredirect=1#comment96237468_54726142), put the filter already in the pattern matching, like:

```
map2 :: [Bool] -> [a] -> [a]
map2 l1 l2 = [ y | (True, y) <- zip l1 l2]
```

Comment: ... or `[ y | (True, y) <- zip l1 l2 ]`.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way I can think of to implement this would be as follows:

```
map2 :: [Bool] -> [a] -> [a]
map2 bs as = map snd $ filter fst $ zip bs as
```

That is, zip the two lists together to get a list of pairs where the first one is the Boolean indicating whether to keep it or not. Then filter to only the ones with `True` in the first slot, and extract their original elements with `map snd`.

Note that the above is an explicit form, in practice I'd probably simplify this to remove the `as` parameter:

```
map2 bs = (map snd) . (filter fst) . (zip bs)
```

Comment: The "pointfree" style is not entirely correct, since this can only "chain" one parameter. You can use the `(.).(.)` operator, but that perhaps makes things a bit "*overcomplicated*". +1 nevertheless for the first attempt.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem oops, you're correct, I should know that by now as I've often tried it and had it not work, and eventually realised this. That should teach me for posting an answer without actually testing it! I'll rewrite as a correct composition by reducing to a function of one parameter rather than zero.

Comment: It's not *too* bad though: `map2 = ((map snd . filter fst) .) . zip`.